# How to restrict Amazon S3 API access?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to create a different identity to (access key / secret key) to access Amazon S3 buckets via the REST API where I can restrict access (read only for example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. The S3 API documentation describes the [Authentication and Access Control](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html) services available to you. You can set up a bucket so that another Amazon S3 account can read but not modify items in the bucket.

Comment: So I setup another S3 account and use it's credentials (key/secret) then?

Comment: That would limit them (meaning one who has this other account credientials) from manipulating that shared bucket, but wouldn't they have unfettered access to that S3 account and store?  Meaning, they could create bucket(s) via the API and upload stuff to their hearts content?

I'm looking specifically for a way to have a client app that can talk to S3 with the restful API but is restricted in what can be done with those credentials.  Namely read-only.

Is that possible?

Comment: You're right that using another S3 account gives that other account the ability to create new buckets. The only way I can think of to do what you suggest is to use *anonymous* access to your S3 bucket. If you choose random enough object names, then people aren't likely to guess the names of your objects. However, you are then responsible for bandwidth costs incurred by the anonymous downloads, and access to your objects aren't limited to authenticated accounts.

Comment: I'm not concerned about people downloading stuff... just don't want them doing anything else.  Read only, as it were.

So the REST API, if used, always applies to a user with full access to the store?  The only way to do something like this is to use a normal HTTP downloading through the object's public URL?

Comment: In order to use the REST API, the other user must be authenticated. To be authenticated, they must have their own Amazon AWS account. Since accounts are independent, you can't restrict what they can do with their own account. Therefore, your only option appears to be public download access.

Answer (score 9):

The recommended way is to use IAM to create a new user, then [apply a policy](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to that user.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the details at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html (follow the link to "Using Query String Authentication")- this is a subdocument to the one Greg Posted, and describes how to generate access URLs on the fly.

This uses a hashed form of the private key and allows expiration, so you can give brief access to files in a bucket without allowed unfettered access to the rest of the S3 store.

Constructing the REST URL is quite difficult, it took me about 3 hours of coding to get it right, but this is a very powerful access technique.